# Send files from Linux (Informatica Server) to File Server(windows)

Tags: sh, powershell-2.0, informatica

I need to create a shell script that will send files from Linux to Windows.

Is this possible?

I can use informatica, but I'm a newbie on this application.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SSH protocol and -scp command via terminal. https://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux

Comment: Thanks. I will check this. :)

Comment: sorry. can you give example of it? can I use this in .sh and run in informatica?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you want to send a file from UNIX/INUX to WIndows. Options are FTP or SFTP.  You can use any simple FTP script which uses FTP command for this. You can write something like this ftp -n << EOS
 open ftpserver
 user ftpuser ftppass
 put abc.csv 
 bye
EOS
Please check - if you want to use local system as target, you may check if you have ability to receive files.

Answer (score -1):

I have not worked withi informatica, at the moment im during the journey, but if you have your server set up over internet you can connect to it, opening terminal, type: ssh username@host, enter your password and  idę another ssh commands to control your server from terminal (for example: send files or manage your SQL databases)